# Get Outlook folders in Postbox

Tags: microsoft-outlook, postbox

Good afternoon.

I have some rules in Outlook to redirect the emails to specific folders.

Now I am using Postbox, and I only receive the emails that are not associated to the rules.

All the emails that are going to the folders are not showing.

Any solution to this situation?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you didn't state if you're on Mac or Windows

Mac: Postbox | Preferences | Accounts |  | Advanced > uncheck the option to "Show only subscribed folders".

Windows: Tools | Options | Accounts |  | Advanced > uncheck the option to "Show only subscribed folders".

If this doesn't work, you'll have to configure the mapping - [configuration tutorial.](http://support.postbox-inc.com/entries/113756-how-to-open-the-config-editor)

Comment: Using Windows, in Postbox 3.0.5, i cannot find that option.

Comment: Find the problem. I was using a POP3 account. Changed to IMAP, and now all working as you suggest.